# How to statically link golang's .a library from C++ project?

Tags: c++, go, static-libraries, static-linking

Golang has a lot of useful libraries but I need to support my C++ application and can't re-write it in Golang (it is too large).

So I'm trying to use Go's libraries (`$GOPATH\pkg\path\to\package\*.a` files) from my C++ application by static linking.

First of all I make simple library (**Golang**):

```
    package math_core
    func Sum(a, b int) int {
        return a + b
    }
```

And **built** this code (in root folder for this project) via following commands:

```
    SET GOOS=windows
    SET GOARCH=386
    go build
    go install
```

(as result I got `libmath.core.a` library)

After it I make simple application which will use this library (**C++**):

```
    #include <iostream>
    extern int Sum(int a, int b);
    int main() {
        std::cout << Sum(5, 7) << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

**I found this articles** in the web:

- [first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765240/could-not-read-symbols-archive-has-no-index-run-ranlib-to-add-one)
- [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5560279/c-64-bits-could-not-read-symbols-archive-has-no-index-run-ranlib-to-add-on?rq=1)
- [third](https://cboard.cprogramming.com/cplusplus-programming/96400-could-not-read-symbols-archive-has-no-index.html)

but it doesn't help me.

I use following **SOFTWARE**:

- Windows 10 x64
- Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers (Neon.3 Release 4.6.3)
- GCC version 4.8.1 20130324 (prerelease) (rubenvb-4.8-stdthread)
- Gogland 1.0 EAP (Build #GO-173.3415.23)
- JRE 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b6 amd64
- Go 1.9.2 windows/amd64

Content of `Z:\\MyProjects\\Math.Console\\` folder:

[image: Files structure]

I trying to statically link `libmath.core.a` library from my `math.console` application **using following commands**:

```
    g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o main.o "..\\main.cpp" 
    g++ "-LZ:\\MyProjects\\Math.Console" -o Math.Console.exe main.o -lmath.core
```

But I got this **OUTPUT**:

```
`Z:\MyProjects\Math.Console/libmath.core.a: could not read symbols: Archive has no index; run ranlib to add one
```

Also I tried to extract `object files (*.o)` from library `libmath.core.a` via

```
    ar -xo libmath.core.a
```

and I got following files:

```
    __.PKGDEF
    _go_.o
    main.o
```

When I trying to see it contents via `nm` I got this:

```
    nm: __.PKGDEF: File format not recognized
    nm: _go_.o: File format not recognized
```

And for `main.o` file from `libmath.core.a` library I got this:

```
00000000 b .bss
00000000 d .ctors
00000000 d .data
00000000 N .debug_abbrev
00000000 N .debug_aranges
00000000 N .debug_info
00000000 N .debug_line
00000000 N .debug_macro
00000000 N .debug_str
00000000 r .eh_frame
00000000 r .rdata$zzz
00000000 t .text
         U ___main
00000058 t ___tcf_0
00000097 t __GLOBAL__sub_I_main
         U __Z3Sumii
0000006a t __Z41__static_initialization_and_destruction_0ii
         U __ZNSolsEi
         U __ZNSolsEPFRSoS_E
         U __ZNSt8ios_base4InitC1Ev
         U __ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev
         U __ZSt4cout
         U __ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_
00000000 b __ZStL8__ioinit
         U _atexit
00000000 T _main
```

But I don't understand how can I use Golang's library from C++ project.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: "Also I tried to extract object files (*.o) from library libmath.core.a and I got ... main.o" The `main.o` file is produced from your C++ source. The only way it would be in the library archive is you had put it in there yourself.

Comment: Also, I highly doubt that Go uses C++-compatible name mangling. In general it seems [impossible to directly call Go from C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713214/how-to-use-c-in-go), so it won't be possible in C++ either.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you need to have your exported function in the `main` package.

Also I think that you need to have an empty main function in that file.

`func main() {}`